# Convertir este codigo al lado del JS

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este input que es para entrar postal code pero esta escrito a manera que solo permite el ingreso de numeros y si escribes letras no funciona, el problema es que esta escrito en el html y se ve horroroso, estoy intentando colocar los eventos del lado del Js pero no consigo que funcionen. Que se les ocurre?

```js
function alpha(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.key : k = e.which;
    return (k == 189 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" required  onkeypress="return alpha(event);" oninput="javascript:
                            if(this.value.length>5){
                            var num_sf=this.value;
                            var num_cf=''
                            num_cf=num_sf.substring(0,5)
                            this.value=num_cf;
                            }" ontouchstart="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" inputmode="tel" maxlength="5">
```

El codigo que yo estoy utilizando es este.

```js
function alpha(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.key : k = e.which;
    return (k == 189 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}

const INPUT_ZIPCODE = document.getElementById('zipcode');
if (INPUT_ZIPCODE) {
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
        e.target.removeAttribute('readonly');
    });
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
        e.target.removeAttribute('readonly');
    });
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        if(e.target.value.length>5){
            var num_sf=e.target.value;
            var num_cf=''
            num_cf=num_sf.substring(0,5)
            e.target.value=num_cf;
        }
    });
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
        return alpha(e);
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" required inputmode="tel" maxlength="5">
```

Comment: Qué exactamente debe suceder al escribir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo de horroroso es cosa de gustos, a mí me gusta más que la alternativa que tu propones.

Tienes 2 problemas:

1. La función alpha está mal. Esta función cuando toma el valor de e.key, el if que le sigue no tiene sentido. Y esto pasa cuando la llamas desde el addEventListener. Toma ese valor en vez de tomar el de e.which
   Yo eliminé esta función y puse esa condición dentro del evento
2. El addEventListener cuando retorna false no cancela el evento (como lo hace cuando está en html) así que debes detenerlo a mano

```js
const INPUT_ZIPCODE = document.getElementById('zipcode');
if (INPUT_ZIPCODE) {
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
        e.target.removeAttribute('readonly');
    });
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
        e.target.removeAttribute('readonly');
    });
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        if(e.target.value.length>5){
            var num_sf=e.target.value;
            var num_cf=''
            num_cf=num_sf.substring(0,5)
            e.target.value=num_cf;
        }
    });
    INPUT_ZIPCODE.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
        if ( !(e.keyCode == 189 || (e.keyCode  >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57))){
        e.preventDefault(); 
     }
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" required  inputmode="tel" maxlength="5">
```

Por otro lado maxlength ya hace lo de limitar la cantidad de caracteres, además remueves el atributo readonly pero nunca se lo habías agregado en primer lugar.
Así que a mi parecer todo tu problema se reduce a:

```js
function alpha(){
  return (event.keyCode  == 189 || (event.keyCode  >= 48 && event.keyCode  <= 57));
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" required  onkeypress="return alpha();" inputmode="tel" maxlength="5">
```

Comment: Un pequeño apunte: el uso de keyboardEvent.which está [desaconsejado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which), es preferible y más legible usar [Keyboard.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Comment: @PabloLozano Ya me parecía raro, nunca había visto esa propiedad. Cambie el código en consecuencia. Gracias por el dato.

Comment: @Yussef Amigo muchisimas gracias, la verdad yo ya habia encontrado ese codigo aca en mi trabajo y pues, tambien vi detalles que no entendi porque estaban puestos como el de readonly pero siempre que pregunté, nadie supo explicarme el porque de eso, muchas gracias, lo hiciste genial.